# go get has a delay getting github push

Tags: go, github

I have a go package that I just modified and pushed an update:

https://github.com/jimsnab/go-cmdline/tags

The tag v1.0.3 is present.

On the same machine that I pushed the change, `git ls-remote --tags origin` shows the v1.0.3 tag.

Now I want to update another module's dependency. I cd into that module directory and run `go get -v -u ./...`. For some reason there is a delay, about 10 minutes, before this works.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Did you try skipping the proxy? If you're not specifying a version, `-u` is only going to find the latest in proxy.golang.org (or whichever you have set). If you want a specific version, specify that with `go get`.

Comment: Ah that's the delay, thank you. BTW if the proxy doesn't know the version (yet), `go get` can't request it.